# Unable to populate a named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into a problem which I'm unable to resolve on my own and was wondering if anyone here could educate me in what I'm doing wrong? The purpose of the code is to transfer a row of information (about 60 cells) to another sheet.

-

To add some more clarity (my last question was difficult to understand):

RProjekt contains the following cells: E6;F15;F17;F19;F21;F23;I6;I8;I10;I15;I17;I19;I21;I23

RBkriterier contains the following cells: F30:K30;F31:K31;F32:K32;F33:K33;F34:K34

Rinser contains the following cells: 
F45:K45;F46:K46;F47:K47;F48:K48;F49:K49

-

I hope the code below illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish. Any suggestions? Grateful for help!

-

```
Dim Bkriterier As Range
Dim Pinformation As Range
Dim inser As Range
Dim AllProjectInformation as range

Set Pinformation = InputSheet_Utveckling.Range("RProjekt") '"InputSheet_Utveckling" is a worksheet
Set Bkriterier = InputSheet_Utveckling.Range("RBkriterier") ' The "R ..." are named ranges consisting of several cells
Set inser = InputSheet_Utveckling.Range("Rinser")
Set AllProjectInformation = Union(Pinformation, Bkriterier, inser)


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To AllProjectInformation.Cells.Count
    AllProjectInformation.Areas(i) = projectRow.Range(i) '"projectRow is from another routine that goes through a table looking for a project code. Once found, that specific row is (and the "address") is stored in projectRow of type ListRow
Next i
```

Comment: Just a blind shot: change ‘For i = 1 To AllProjectInformation.Cells.Count’ to ‘For i = 1 To AllProjectInformation.Areas.Count?

Comment: I think your problem is that you created a new range object by `UNION`. Are you not trying to step through each cell of this new range object rather than using `Areas`? > `For each cl in AllProjectInformation............<code>............Next cl`

Comment: `For Each` is the only way to step through the cells of a merged range reliably - if you use a loop counter then you will end up accessing cells which are not in your merged range (it will start to count cells adjacent to the first `Area` but not contained in it)

Comment: @timwilliams, that is great. Thank you. I clearly have to read up more on areas. Any chance you have a suggestion for an alternative code? "projectRow" is a specific row from a table on a different sheet and it contains about 60 cells. I'm not sure how to loop through all the cells on "projectRow" without using an index.

Comment: @JvdV, please see above. I was unable to tag 2 users in one comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a comparison of non-working (For loop counter) and a working (For Each loop) approaches to filling a merged non-contiguous range from a single contiguous Range:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rngMerged As Range, rngRow As Range, c As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Yellow and grey areas
    Set rngMerged = Application.Union(Range("B2:B6"), Range("D2:D6"))

    'Green-shaded area
    Set rngRow = Range("F2:O2")

    'Here we're trying to fill rngMerged cell-by-cell from rngRow...

    'Method 1 - does not work as expected
    For i = 1 To rngMerged.Cells.Count
        rngMerged.Cells(i).Value = rngRow.Cells(i).Value
    Next i

    'Method 2 - fills as expected
    i = 0
    For Each c In rngMerged.Cells
        i = i + 1
        c.Value = rngRow.Cells(i).Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

Method 1 outcome: using a For loop counter we end up filling only the first area of the merged range (and then extending outside of that area as the loop progresses)

[image]

Method 2 outcome: the `For Each` method of looping over the merged range hits each cell as expected, and we can index into the single-area range `rngRow.Cells` reliably using `i`

[image]

**Note:** the order in which you Union the ranges will affect the order in which cells are looped over in the the `For Each` loop, so you have some control there how cells in your merged area map to the cells in your `projectRow` source range.

Comment: thank you so much. So elegant and I truly appreciate the explanation of the behavior of "union" so I can avoid similar mistakes going forward. On a side note, would you recommend using "application" as much as possible (whenever applicable) for a more stable code & execution?

Comment: I probably don't use application everywhere possible - typically only for Union/Intersect, ScreenUpdating, Calculation settings etc, and when using worksheet functions in VBA.